# SQL in java - get the number of columns

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I've been using sql with java for a while now. The code typically goes like this -

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd); 
PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table");
ResultSet rs = pstat.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
  System.out.print(rs.getString(1) + "," + rs.getString(2) + "...");
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the total count of columns. I never needed it because I had access to DBVisualizer and knew the exact number of columns from there. However, I now want to write a java program that prints out all the results of the query and so, need the number of columns so I can print all of them in the while loop instead of guessing. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Documentation is your friend. the Last paragraph of the javadoc for ResultSet explicitly tells you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html. aside from that, using `select *` is generally a bad idea for this reason. Select the columns you want and you don't have an issue.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but finding it without your pointer would've been a needle in a haystack. Most of the questions on this site were probably answered in some document some where.

Comment: @BrianRoach just ask for the metadata of the resultset and "select *" is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) - Returns the number of columns in this `ResultSet` object.

```
ResultSet rs = pstat.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

See [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)